# What would constitute a good selection of medium power and gain transistors that are modern equivalents of discontinued parts?

Tags: components, repair

TLDR: I need to build a collection of NPN and PNP transistors(mostly medium powered complementary audio amplifier transistors) in order to avoid constantly ordering specific parts and waiting for them to arrive. Packaging and pin configuration is not important; what I am more concerned about are common combinations of Vce, hFE, Ic, Ipc, and Veb.  What would be decent selection of five to ten sets of modern complementary pair replacements I might order to cover most of my needs?

---

Background: I am an engineer that recently got a fantastic job that is very laid back(I can work whenever I like) repairing vintage electronics, mostly amplifiers.  The company had previously been buying old electronics from garage sales, flea markets, etc, and repairing any very simple problems they found(such as frayed power cords, replacing belts in cassette decks, or cosmetic issues) that didn't include any sort of electronic diagnosis.  Any units they couldn't repair themselves, they started storing in the back warehouse several years ago, so there is now a huge backlog of items in need of repair.  Since they had no technician previously, they had no replacement parts on hand, and had been discarding any non-working electronics that weren't worth any money non-working.  Upon my arrival, I immediately put a halt to the disposal of non-working items in order to be able to later salvage parts, and in the last few months have sourced at least a hundred parts from the broken items we have since collected.  I also built up a large stock of new capacitors, resistors, linear regulators, and low power transistors in order to facilitate my repairs in a timely manner.  High powered output transistors are expensive, and will still need to be ordered on an as-needed basis, but I would like to order a selection of modern medium powered transistors that would be common replacements for older discontinued transistors.  As an example, I once ordered many extra modern BD139/BD140 transistors when I needed one of each for a specific repair, and I have since used the extras to successfully replace several other older discontinued transistors of various part numbers.  I would like to know if anyone with extensive repair experience would know the part numbers of the most commonly used modern replacements transistors, like the BD139/140s I have been frequently using.

Comment: Note: I hope this isn't off topic due to possibly being considered a product recommendation.  I know product recommendations are off topic here due to the fact that a particular recommended product might be later discontinued, but I am specifically asking for suggestions for parts(not brand specific) that are currently in production and are NOT likely to be discontinued in the near future.

Comment: And, yes, it's also a "list" answer, i guess, but I feel a good answer to this question may be very helpful to others in the future...

Comment: This is "Shopping" which is off-topic for this site. But generic modern part numbers might start with TIP, MJE, BC, etc. You are basically asking for a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Sparky256 - Yes, as I stated above, but I am not asking for a specific product/brand, but rather for series parts that are produced by several different manufacturers.  Another set of transistors that I previously ordered extras of that I have frequently used to replace other parts are the TIP41c/TIP42c pair.  I am familiar with the families, but they have many members, and only a few of them can be used as common generic replacements...

Comment: If there is a better SE for this question, please feel free to migrate it! I hang out here, so though I would ask here first.  At least you guys might know where it should go...

Comment: VTC, but a common sense approach would be for you to look at the list of the ones you bought so far and perhaps start stocking the top 3.

Comment: If you have ample time, I would suggest your try to build a class D amplifier board on your own. You can use all the modern components and circuit design techniques and build a compact board to replace the old ones. It would be a very fruitful exercise in circuit design and PCB implementation. You can get a PCB fabricated and even assembled at very low prices from Chinese vendors.

Comment: To choose a transistor, you analyse the application requirements and not bodge in (with a prayer) something you might have on the shelf in your lab. This is a shopping question and has no future benefit to this site.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig - I have built amplifiers before, and while a fun exercise, would provide no benefit in my situation, where the customers that purchase the items I repair wish the units to appear internally and externally as close to original as possible.

Comment: OK. I now understand that the amplifiers you repair are preferred for their historic value, not performance. I struggle to appreciate that concept, but I guess it's not a bad idea from your role as long as you get reasonably paid for it.

Answer (score 0):

Start with TIP122, TIP125 pair. You can use it in many places. They have excellent current gain and fair enough voltage and current rating.

For even higher power rating, you can go to TIP142, TIP147.

For a bit lower power, BD139, BD140 pair is a nice option.

Comment: I actually did find a few kits that contain a TIP assortment of 31c/32c, 41c/42c(which I already have many of), and several TIP120 somethings.  When I looked up the 120 series, they appeared to be darlingtons with extremely high gain, and I don't remember having ever repaired a unit that required such a high gain transistor.  I will check into the 143 and 147.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a curve tracer, I suggest you examine various candidates, and select part numbers with high Early Voltage (flatter output curves).

This parameter controls the power-supply-rejection of these devices,

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct, I don't agree that TIP121,122 Series are appropriate replacement equivalents to the industry standard work horse like the BD139,140. As the former are more mundane medium power transistors whereas many of the TIP series transistors are often Darlingtons with power, yes, but with ample gain, a feature that may not be required in the application that you wish to substitute in.

Comment: The TIP series is still in production with many options, not always Darlingtons. Also MJE series is widely used.